# Find the closed-form expression for $c_n$ of this recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrences

$$c_{n + 1} = 2\cdot|c_n| - \sqrt{c_n^2 + 16}$$ with $c_0 = 3$.

My question on math stackexchange was closed because lack of details. Let me clarify: I'm an amateur novelist, I don't know anything about Math. I'm not even English speaker. I accidentally derived this sequence when drawing an ellipse with geogebra. I only want to know if there is a closed-form expression for $c_n$ or not. Please don't be too harsh on me, bros. Normally I will not follow a Math problem that long. But I really found this sequence to be beautiful. I tried my best but can't find $c_n$. I'm hopeless. More than four weeks with no progress. Please don't close this.

How it was derived: ellipse $(E0)$ has $a = 5, b = 4, c = 3$. Ellipse $(E1)$ has the same $b$ but $c$ minus to $a - c$ so $c_1 = c_0 - (a_0 - c_0) = 2\cdot c_0 - a_0$. It is then generalized to $c_{n + 1} = 2\cdot c_n - a_n$ and $a_n = \sqrt{c_n^2 + b^2}$ then we have the above recurrence relationship. Note: because $c_n$ could change sign (direction) and we only talk about distant so it must take by absolute value as the equation on the top of my question.

If it just doesn't have any closed-form expression then I hope this sequence could help the research of chaotic theory. I don't know if I'm the first to discover it or it's already discovered but I don't know. I'm too tired and I quit. This problem is beyond my ability. Bye.

Comment: Likely there is none.  The best you can say is that the numbers are algebraic, and likely of increasing complexity.  A good start would be to graph the right hand side and find its fixed points. Then you could see where the sequence is headed and maybe how fast.  However, there are simpler sequences which inspired the study of chaos theory and fractals, so no promises.  I am not sure this forum is a good one for your question. Gerhard "Maybe It Makes Pretty Pictures" Paseman, 2020.03.16.

Comment: The function behind this sequence looked to be like normal sine or cosine but it's not. Because I could get $c_n$ very close to $0$ or $4$ but it will never equals. I use Excel and I found the rule: after a $c_k$ very close to $\dfrac{4}{\sqrt3}$ there is a $c_{k + 1}$ very close to $0$ and the next $c_{k + 2}$ is very close to $4$. So after $c_k$ is $min$ the next $c_{k + 1}$ is max. It's beautiful. Edit: this is the absolution version of this series, not itself. I first use distance so everything must be non negative so I take absolute value of the right hand side.

Comment: This later version is also encoded information about when $c_k$ changed sign. When the value is negative it's mean $c_k$ changed direction. The positive direction I have chosen is the same as the line number.

Comment: I observed when I plot it with the $a_n$ sequence it will have a very similar graph to the one I saw about chaotic theory on wikipedia. I updated my question for more information.

Comment: My original purpose when I keep trying to study this sequence because my knowledge about basic sequence when I still in school told me there should be a function behind any sequence. So I tried to find the closed-form expression $c_n$ so I could extend the variable from the natural $n$ to the real $x$. It turned out to be not that easy and I'm even got stressed because of this. I admit I'm defeated and hope someday someone will revisit and hopefully could do what I'm failed to do. Now I think I should back to my normal work which is a novelist. Bye.

Comment: @jiaxing, "there should be a function behind any sequence" is an old and natural intuition, but it turned out to be somehow too optimistic. We must live with the fact that even simple iterations do not have simple closed forms... This is why people invented dynamical systems and other qualitative theories after all ---and these topics may give you more fun and more satisfaction.

Comment: You should include in the body of your question here alink to the stackexchange question, and you should include there a link to your question here.

Comment: The stackexchange question, which gathered some helpful comments, is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582995/find-the-equation-of-this-recursive-sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gerhard Paseman noted, the existence of a closed-form expression here is unlikely. However, we can show that the sequence $(c_n)$ is bounded but not convergent, which explains your observations.

Indeed, $c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$ for $n=0,1,\dots$, where $f(x):=2|x|-\sqrt{x^2+16}$.

If $c_n\to c$ (as $n\to\infty$), then $f(c)=c$, so that $c=c_*:=-\sqrt2$. Also, $q:=|f'(c_*)|=|-5/3|=5/3>1$. So, $|c_{n+1}-c_*|=|f(c_n)-f(c_*)|\sim q|c_n-c_*|>|c_n-c_*|$ unless $c_n=c_*$ for all $n$, which is not the case, since $c_0=3\ne c_*$. So, the assumption $c_n\to c$ leads to a contradiction; that is, the sequence $(c_n)$ is not convergent.

Let us now show that the sequence $(c_n)$ is bounded. First here, $f\ge f(0)=-4$. Next, the function $f$ is even, whence $f([-4,3])=f([-4,0])$. Also, $f$ is decreasing on $(\infty,0]$, whence $f([-4,0])=[f(0),f(-4)]\subset[-4,3]$. So, $f([-4,3])\subset[-4,3]$. Also, $c_0=3\in[-4,3]$. Thus, $c_n\in[-4,3]$ for all $n$.

---

Here is a picture showing the graphs $\{(x,f(x))\colon x\in[-4,3]\}$ (yellow) and $\{(x,x)\colon x\in[-4,3]\}$ (blue), together with the "evolution" $(\overrightarrow{A_0A_1},\overrightarrow{A_1A_2},\dots,\overrightarrow{A_{19}A_{20}})$, where $(A_0,\dots,A_{20}):=\big((c_0,c_1),(c_1,c_1),(c_1,c_2),(c_2,c_2),\dots,(c_9,c_{10}),(c_{10},c_{10})\big)$:

[image]

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's currently the best I could get.

Comment: The sequence is indeed has two version: my original is like this: $c_{n+1} = |2\cdot c_n - \sqrt{c_n^2 + 16}|$ and I studied this sequence intensively via Excel. You could try with this sequence because it has less information than the modified one above (which also encoded sign of $c_n$ which is the information when $c_n$ changed direction with the positive direction is the same as the line number. Sorry if you can't understand my words because it's not the first time. People seemed to not easy to understand my messages or sometimes even misunderstood. I'm very sorry for my poor English :(

Comment: This is when I plotted the series: https://imgur.com/SJB4AfZ

Comment: This is when I use the software's smooth curve approximation algorithm: https://imgur.com/Z7OOK0t . This is what I believed to be the graph of the function behind this sequence if it's extended to real value $x$ instead of the natural $n$. It motived me to find this function, thus give rise the this problem.

Comment: My final comment: This is when I plot $c_n$ together with $a_n$, you could see the graph is very similar to the one of chaotic theory page in wikipedia: https://imgur.com/G7f6hWm . This is everything I know about this sequence. Other attribute of it can be easily derived from it equation using algebra. Bye.